# Time Complexity of the following code fragment?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

[image]

I calculated it to be O(N^2), but my instructor marked it incorrect in the exam. The Correct answer was O(1). Can anyone help me, how did the time complexity come out to be O(1)?

Comment: looks like N log N ...

Comment: My Instructor marked it as O(1)..

Comment: Ask you instructor to give you motivations cuz it's not.....as already written it's O(NlogN)

Comment: The outer loop does already 2N, how can it be O(1). The inner loop does log2(N) => O(N log N)

Comment: my mistake...the algorithm in exam was slightly modified..while(j<=0)..the loop would have never been executed..so O(1)...silly me..:p

Comment: @panther1 : It happens. However the complexity was neither O(N^2). I hope you have still learned something new.

Comment: Yup..I get it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer `loop` will run for `2N` times. (`int j = 2 * N`) and later decrementing everytime by `1`)

And since `N` is not changing, and the `i` is assigned the values of `N` always (`int i = N`), the inner `loop` will always run for `logN base 2` times.
(Notice the way `i` changes `i = i div 2`)

Therefore, the complexity is `O(NlogN)`

Comment: I've never seen this **base 2** in complexity definitions

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, I am giving this because `i = i div 2`. If it was `i = i div 3`, it would have been **base 3**.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Usually you don't add it because all log are equivalent in complexity (`log_b(x) = log(x) / log(b)`), and `log(b)` is a constant.

Comment: The base of the logarithm is actually irrelevant, it is an asymptotic estimation.

Comment: @xbirkettx Haris mentions clearly N log N, so he knows... Doesn't hurt to give the OP the absolute exact number of iterations though.

Comment: @ringø, I actually mentioned with the **base** in the beginning, later I edited after he pointed out. :)

Comment: @xbirkettx, I agree, during the definition, one can give the **base** to make people understand. Later in the asymptotic notation, it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Question:* What happens when you repeatedly half input(or search space) ?(Like in Binary Search).

*Answer:* Well, you get **log(N)** complexity. (Reference : The Algorithm Design Manual by *Steven S. Skiena*)

See the inner loop in your algorithm, `i = i div 2` makes it a **log(N)** complexity loop. Therefore the overall complexity will be **N log(N)**.

Take this with a pinch of salt : Whenever you divide your input (search space) by 2, 3 , 4 or whatever constant number greater than 1, you get `log(N)` complexity.

P.S. : the complexity of your algorithm is nowhere near to **O(1)**.